# NLP discover city, state and Name from the given text

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I have a text file which was generated from an image using OCR (optical character recognition). The file contains records of information where part of each record contains a text of the format Customer name city and state. A sample of text is below

Benjamin Meeks Decatur , GA

Some times the text may be split across multiple lines. The text will always be in the given order. I have a static list of cities and states but still some records and states can come out of the list. The comma between the state and city may or may not present. The city and state text mostly would contain USA, UK, Canada, Australia etc.

From one my friend i came to know natural language processing can solve mining the categories of text from the given input.  I am noob to NLP so i am here for suggestions what are the techniques of NLP i can apply to extract the city, state and name.

I have googled for an openNLP library seems like apache openNLP seems to be the good library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start with NLP I think OpenNLP is a good choice, another Java option could be StandfordNLP. If you are familiar with Python then go with NLTK.

About your problem I think that **Named Entity Recognition** is what you should look for. Is better if first you learn the basic of NLP and then use this specific "tecnique".
However [here](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.recognition) you can already find the OpenNLP chapter about this; as you can see you could also train your "code" in order to recognize exactly what you want, using machine learning techniques.
For OpenNLP there already exist some trained model for Location, Organization, Person ect. ([here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/))